# Howto Enable Email Verification in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

How do I enable email verification in B2C w/ custom policies?

In an attempt to reverse engineer it, I tried disabling it in a built-in policy and downloaded the policy.  I tried adding that metadata item to my self-asserted technical profile but that didn't work.

**Reverse Engineer Test | Built-In Policy**

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-Input">
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">False</Item>
  </Metadata>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

**My Self-Asserted Technical Profile**

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUp">
    <DisplayName>User signup</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">True</Item>
    </Metadata>
    ...
</TechnicalProfile>
```

I'm using usernames for local accounts incase that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether a local account is created with an email address- or user name-based sign-in name, you add email verification by adding `PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email"` to the "email" output claim of your self-asserted technical profile, as follows:

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
```

Comment: Could you add to what adding email verification means in this context? Does it take care of the entire process of sending the email with verification code to the specified user if there is one? Also, would you happen to know a way to extract the verification code from this, if this is the only indication of email verification in B2C?

Comment: Hi @BenjaminJohn Yes, you're right, `Verified.Email` implements the end-to-end interactions of generating a verification code, sending it in a partially-customizable e-mail message to the e-mail recipient, and then validating what is submitted by the end user. If you want a fully-customizable e-mail message, then you must use [a display control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email) (currently in preview).

Comment: @ChrisPadgett would you by any chance have any idea about why the control disappears when you pre-populate the email as inputclaim? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61661133/email-verification-box-disappears-when-passing-email-from-facebook-as-input-clai