# Multi step Sign Up form for local account AD B2C custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm working on azure AD b2c custom policies, i'm not an expert. I have created signup page using [starter pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/LocalAccounts) and added a new text field to it. Now i want to split the sign up screen into two.

First page:
Will have Some fields like Name, Given Name etc. and continue button. When i click the button it should show the Second page.

Second page:
Will contain the rest of the fields in the form and create button. When clicks Create it create the user.

How can i achieve this? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create two [self-asserted pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile).

You can control the buttons by e.g. "setting.showContinueButton".

You then have two steps in your user journey, one for each self-asserted page.

Comment: I have a scenario where user can signin using email or phone number, i have the policies. Now i need a multi step signup form, like before collecting the Email, phone and password i need to collect a value say "City" from the user and need to validate the city using an azure function. This need to be done in two steps.

Step 1: Collect the city and validate

Step 2: Collect Email, phone and password. Verify email and verify phone.

And city we are collecting in the first step need to sent to the application in the token after a successful user journey (sign in or signup)

Comment: I have tried the steps you provided on the answer that worked with a sample one, but it is not working with actual policies.

Comment: Verified email - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49574334/howto-enable-email-verification-in-azure-ad-b2c Verified phone - look in the MFA startup pack. Send city in token - make sure it is a persisted claim - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile#persistedclaims

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just used "SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa", the existing policy customisation is bit difficult. It is not working properly, Giveing 500 error, so decided to use "SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa". How to customise this "SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa" to support login via email or phone?

Comment: I mean i commented FB login from "SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa", now i need to login using either phone or email which we verified during signup.

Comment: I was meaning more of a take the XML from the MFA sample and copy into yours. There's some use cases here that may help - https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples